# Diff Word docx files in Sourcetree on Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, diff, docx, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been trying to get a text diff of Word .docx files working in Sourcetree on Windows 7. I have followed the instructions here [Using Microsoft Word with git](http://blog.martinfenner.org/2014/08/25/using-microsoft-word-with-git/) to use Pandoc and can get it working from the command line. Unfortunately I can't get that diff to appear in Sourcetree. Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?

Here's my .gitattributes file that I've put in the root of my project:

```
# Add diff of docx files.
*.docx diff=word
```

Here's my .git\config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[diff "word"]
  textconv=pandoc --to=markdown
  prompt = false
[alias]
  wdiff = diff --word-diff=color --unified=1
```

Comment: You might be interested in https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1416 , however that ticket wasn't closed

Comment: Thanks for the link. That suggests that I'm not going to get this working.

Comment: Yes it suggests that this is not implemented in source tree

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem. Pandoc seems not to be working well with SourceTree, and I was wondering if there's a valid alternative. Then I remembered that WinMerge solved this years ago with an external tool, *xdocdiff*. The steps:

- If you haven't already, download xdocdiff [here](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiffPlugin/en/), you can install as suggested or put in a folder you like;
- Add the folder in the Windows `PATH` variable, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) (a reboot is required to take effect);
- Verify that everything works by typing in a Command Line window the command `xdoc2txt`, the output will be the usage helper (like below):

  ```
   > xdoc2txt
   Usage: xdoc2txt [-s|-e|-j][-c][-f][-r=(0|1|2)] <filename...>
           -s : convert to ShiftJIS(default)
           -e : convert to EUC
           -j : convert to JIS
           -f : output to file
           -c : activate PDF cache
           -p : print property
           -n : ignore permission on PDF;(require cryptlib.dll)
           -r=(0|1|2) : ruby style(0:suppress 1:parentheses 2:aozora bunko
           -o=0 : other option; -o=0:no show PDF page#
           -g=# : PDF gap parameter
           -v : show version number
           -x : output existing cell only(for EXCEL2007)
  ```

**go on only if this command works**;

- Add or edit the `.gitattributes` file in the root of the project:

  ```
   *.doc diff=xdoc2txt
   *.xls diff=xdoc2txt
   *.docx diff=xdoc2txt
   *.xlsx diff=xdoc2txt
   # ...
   # add any other supported extensions you need
  ```
- Edit the `.git\config` file in the root of the project:

  ```
   [diff "xdoc2txt"]
     textconv = xdoc2txt
     cachetextconv = true
     binary = true
     prompt = false
  ```

These lines allows me to see the diff preview inside SourceTree.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only person that's tried to do this. However, I've tried following your instructions and I still can't get it to work. Which version of SourceTree are you using? I have version 1.6.22.0.

Comment: Mine is 1.6.20.0. Be sure that opening a Windows' Command line, if you type the command `xdoc2txt` it will not return a _command not found_ error.

Comment: Did you get the stage or discard hunk commands to work?
Showing the diff works for the current version 2.4.7.0 but whenever I try discarding a hunk I get an error: 'git apply' failed with code 1: [...]
error: while searching for [...].
Well I guess there might still be missing something for the way back from sourcetree to the corresponding hunks?

Comment: how do you do it with mercurial?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with both pandoc or xdoc2txt after having set SourceTree > Tools > Options > Git > Use System Git !!